# Migrate PostgreSQL DB from Multipass to Cloud?

Tags: postgresql, multipass

I have a PostgreSQL database running on Ubuntu in a Canonical Multipass instance on MacOS.  I'd like to migrate its data to a cloud DB (Digital Ocean in this case).  Is it possible to publicly expose that database with public connection strings in Multipass?

Comment: None of this is a problem regarding Ubuntu.

Comment: Multipass is a software from Canonical that runs Ubuntu VMs.  I've updated the question to reflect that more clearly.

Comment: You need to -export- a postgress db  and copy it over to a cloud DB. The OS you do that with does not matter.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I can do that.  That wasn't the question.  I'm interested whether I can gain external network access to the DB, or whether Multipass has that locked down.